# How can I conditionally import a module?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8

I have been playing around with the iOS 8 beta, but I noticed it is impossible to compile to older devices when using

```
@import LocalAuthentication;
```

It simply refuses to compile. I was wondering if it is possible to somehow only include that framework when the device has the Touch ID sensor or if it is an iPhone 5s (less desirable, but it would work). Then, I would need a way to only include the method that handles the Touch ID login if the framework has been successfully imported.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works fine for me with a 6 or 7 deployment target. (And you should be able to get the desired effect by making the framework "Optional"; I can't remember if that's the default or not, but if not you could explicitly make it so in the target settings.)

However, this framework doesn't work for me (with any deployment target, including 8) when building for the simulator. This seems like an SDK bug to me; could this be your issue?

Comment: I made the framework optional, but it still doesn't work. For me, it only compiles when the target is an iPhone 5S (physical device, not the simulator)

Comment: ld: framework not found LocalAuthentication
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: @Alex, I still can't reproduce this on anything but the simulator. I just made a new project and added `@import LocalAuthentication`, changed the deployment target to 7 and it built & ran on my iOS 7 iPad just fine. Can you provide a sample project or full build log?

Comment: I think I figured it out. I was adding it within the project settings and using <code>@import</code> at the same time. Using only <code>@import</code> seems to have fixed it. Thanks!

Comment: @alex something like #if INCLUDE_LOCALAUTH @import</code> #endif